# Deploying and Using OpenZeppelin PaymentSplitter in Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, react, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I currently have a contract that is creating an "item" for a customer to purchase. I've managed to follow a well put together tutorial for implementing this contract into my test network using Ganache and also displaying/executing the contract via Web3 using the React framework.

My question is about using OpenZeppelin's PaymentSplitter contract. I've imported into a subcontract that I created called SplitFunds:

```
contract SplitFunds is PaymentSplitter {
    constructor (address[] memory payees, uint256[] memory shares)
    PaymentSplitter(payees, shares)
    public payable{}
}
```

With this code I was wondering how would I call this function in my Web3 instance? I know how to call other functions in my Items contract.

Thanks